# Appointments Booking Using Slots

Tags: architecture, class, django, class-diagram

I'm looking for an efficient way to create appointments between teachers and students.

I want teacher to be able of make their students know their availabilities : For example, A Teacher writes on the application that he is free for an appointment on Monday from 8am to 9am. The Student wants an appointment with his teacher. The Student checks free time slots of his teacher and choose the appointment on Monday from 8am to 8.30am. A second Student want an appointment and the application have to show him only the free time of the Teacher from 8.30am to 10am on Monday and not from 8am to 8.30 because now this time slot is busy with the first student appointment.

How can I model this ? For example with a class diagram.

I'm thinking about creating a class of dailySchedule for the teacher with time hour slot boolean fields in which 0 means free and 1 means busy. When a student choose an appointment from 8am to 8.30am, the field slot_8_8h_30 equals to 1. Then, in a AppointmentBook class, the appointment is added. If the row corresponding to the appointment is deleted, the field slot_8_8h_30 come backs to 0.

But with this technique, I have to make many conditions to write a row in AppointmentBook :

```
if slot_8_h30:
    timeslot = 0
elif slot_8h30_9h:
    timeslot = 1
elif
etc.
```

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: I'm thinking about creating a class of dailySchedule for the teacher with time hour slot boolean fields in which 0 means free and 1 means busy. When a student choose an appointment from 8am to 8.30am, the field slot_8_8h_30 equals to 1. Then, in a AppointmentBook class, the appointment is added. If the row corresponding to the appointment is deleted, the field slot_8_8h_30 come backs to 0.

Comment: To start with, you may have a look at [this scheduling answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64193807/3723423):  take the "alternative approach",  replace "Classroom" with "Teacher", "RoomSlot" with "TeacherSlot" and "Course" with "Student".  If this is not sufficient, ask a more focused question with your own model, and explain why it doesn't work as needed :-)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I want but in this model, how can I allow the Teacher to show their availabilities to their students ? Am I forced to store the availabilities of the teacher in a table 'Availability' ?

Comment: _" application have to show him only the free time of the Teacher from 8.30am to 10am"_ Why suddenly 10am?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more than one way to skin this particular cat. You could store only the appointments, and generate the slotted time schedule on the fly when requested, or you could store all the slots and individually indicate their status (open/reserved) so that you don't have to do on-the-fly calculation.

Which approach you take depends on where your priorities lie. The former approach keeps the storage size down at the cost of some computational performance, whereas the latter favors performance over storage size.

*Based on your question, I surmise you are a junior profile. I mention this because this is why I'm choosing to pick a simple and readable example rather than a highly performant one.*

If you store all timeslots including the available ones, there is no calculation to be done. Your database will already contain the needed information, so it's a straightforward query to find out the availability.

If you want to only store appointments and calculate availability on the fly, then you're going to need to figure out that calculation. Assume your appointments are stored like this:

| ID | TeacherId | StudentId | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 8:00 | 8:30 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 9:00 | 11:30 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 9:00 | 9:30 |

*For the sake of example, I am ignoring dates and only focusing on the time. In reality, these columns will contain datetimes, which inherently solves the date issue without needing to change the query itself.*

To generate an availability calendar, first you generate the timeslots of that calendar. Let's assume you've generated a list of all slots, and each slot has a start and end time.

Once you've generated a list of all slots, you can iterate over them to check their availability. Checking for overlapping periods (i.e. the appointment and the timeslot) is a common problem that has been solved many times over. [Here is one of those resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513932/algorithm-to-detect-overlapping-periods).

So your query will essentially do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    Appointments a
WHERE
    a.TeacherId = @teacherId
    AND a.Start < @timeslotEnd
    AND @timeSlotStart < a.End
```

You have to fill in `@teacherId`, `@timeSlotStart` and `@timeslotEnd` accordingly. I'm no Django dev and am unaware of how to achieve parametrized SQL queries in Django.

Note also that you could build a student schedule by swapping the teacher ID filter for a student ID filter.

If the returned count is 0, there is no appointment in that time period (= available). If the returned count is higher, there is an appointment (= busy).

So the logic will be something along the lines of:

```
var teacherId = 1;
var timeSlots = GenerateAllTimeSlots();

foreach(var timeSlot in timeSlots)
{
    int rowCount = ExecuteQuery(teacherId, timeSlot.Start, timeSlot.End);

    timeSlot.IsAvailable = (rowCount == 0);
}
```

I'm no Django dev, but I hope the pseudocode helps explain the steps:

```
Define teacher ID
Get all time slots
For each time slot:
    Run the query for the given teacher ID and time slot start/end
    If 0 rows counted
        Time slot is available
    Else
        Time slot is unavailable
```

Comment: Thank you. But the Teacher have to inform his availabilities for each day to their Students. How can I generate the available time slots and save it for each Teacher ?

Comment: How can I know which student have reserved the appointment with the latter favor if I have boolean fields ?

Comment: And how the generated time slot list is related to the appointment table ?

Comment: @anthonya: 1. Your question asked about available/busy notation ("the application have to show him only the free time of the Teacher"), not appointment details. However, changing the query to `SELECT StudentId` instead of `SELECT COUNT(*)` would be a good first step. 2. You're talking about timeslots, so you have therefore defined what these time slots are. This could be every whole hour, or every half hour (xx:00 and xx:30) or every 15 min (xx:00, xx:15, xx:30, xx:45). However you define your timeslot, you can generate a list of timeslots across a day by just iteratively doing `+= increment`.

Comment: Thank you. I mean that teachers have a calendar with time slot availabilities to show to their student in order to student to choose their appointment according to the time slot availability. This is something that teachers have to choose and store before allowing student to choose the stored available time slot appointment and flagged it as busy.

Comment: @anthonya: That's no longer what the question was about. If you have additional question, I suggest you post a new question.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I detailed more my question here : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/430973/appointments-using-time-slots