# Appointments using time slots

Tags: architecture, object-oriented-design, class, django, class-diagram

I would like to create a dynamic appointment system between teacher and student to easily allow them to make an appointment.

In this system, teachers select their 30 minutes time slot availabilities during the following 10 days. They can be available from 9am to 22pm.

Then, students can see their teacher's time slot availabilities and can choose the time slot available they want to make an appointment.
The time slot becomes busy and is reserved for the student.

The teacher can have several appointments a day.
The student can only have one appointment with one teacher. Once the appointment is canceled or is passed, the student can choose an other appointment.

I tried to create separated Appointment class and Availability class :

**Appointment:**

- teacher id ;
- student id ;
- start_time_slot ;
- end_time_slot ;
- date of the day.

**Availabilities:**

- teacher id ;
- date of the day ;
- boolean slot_9h_9h30 ;
- boolean slot_9h30_10h ;
  ...
- boolean slot_21h30_22h.

But how to relate them to have slot_hour variables False when there is an appointment at the same time slot hour in the Appointment class ?

Maybe you have a better solution to propose me ?

Comment: How is this different from your other question: [Appointments Booking Using Slots](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/430892/appointments-booking-using-slots)

Comment: I was told me that I should post a new question (@Flater) to be more specific on my problem. The last question was about making an appointment without seeing the teacher's availabilities. Here, the student can "see" (in the sense that it is stored) the teacher's availabilities before making an appointment.

Comment: _"I was told me that I should post a new question (@Flater) to be more specific on my problem."_ Correction: I suggested posting a new question because you asked a different question than what was initially posted, not because the original question begged elaboration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to do the same thing twice. You're storing the appointment time in the appointment *and* relate it to a specific timeslot.
You should be done one or the other, not both. The problem with doing both is that you open the door to inconsistencies, e.g. having an appointment from 14:00 to 14:30 in the timeslot from 9:00 to 9:30.

Instead, have a single source of truth, and calculate the other from that single source of truth. To test my claim, let's imagine a list of appointments for a given day:

| ID | TeacherId | StudentId | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 8:00 | 8:30 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 9:00 | 11:30 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 9:00 | 9:30 |

Based on only this information, and no time slot table, I am able to create that timeslot calendar for a given teacher. Simply put:

```
 Teacher 1
-----------

07:00 | Available
07:30 | Available
08:00 | Busy (student 1)
08:30 | Available
09:00 | Busy (student 2) 
09:30 | Busy (student 2)
10:00 | Busy (student 2) 
10:30 | Busy (student 2)
11:00 | Busy (student 2) 
11:30 | Available
12:00 | Available
12:30 | Available
```

This proves the point that you don't need both the list of appointments and the timeslot table in order to be able to show someone's availability. One can be calculated from the other.

The answer I provided on [your earlier question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/430892/appointments-booking-using-slots) on the same topic already shows how you can dynamically calculate the content of a time-slot agenda based on a list of saved appointments.

Based on the intention of your question, I would also consider looking at a tutorial surrounding [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), which teaches you the skill of avoiding duplicate data or liable contradictions in a data source.

Comment: That's fine as soon as the teacher doesn't want to set up its availability in advance, something I suspect the OP also wants or needs. I would dare to say that his/her app is similar to a flight booking system where availability (seats) are treated as an asset. You can turn the "student" field into nullable and say "if it's null, it's available" but it's a bit confusing an "appointment" without "attendant". It would turn the entry into something else but an appointment.